# Changing libpath in R does not take effect

Tags: r, environment

Am trying to change the `.libpaths()` in R

Currently I see the below two paths

```
.libPaths()
```

> [1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.5/library"
> [2]
> "C:/Users/test/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpkj8NNm/renv-system-library"

However, I would like to retain only the 1st libpath

So, I tried the below

```
myPaths <- c("C://Program Files//R//R-4.0.5//library")

.libPaths(myPaths)

.libPaths()
```

But still I see both the paths as output

```
.libPaths()
[1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.5/library"                                
[2] "C:/Users/ephssmk/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpkj8NNm/renv-system-library"
```

Can help me retain only the 1st path as .libpaths()?

If temp folder should definitely be there in `.libpaths`, why is it storing under `renv-system-library`?

Comment: What does `. libpaths(. Libpaths())` return?! (on phone, can't use correct function case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the `renv` sandbox library. It's discussed a bit in the FAQ, as well as in `?renv::config`, but it probably deserves some more documentation elsewhere.

https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/faq.html

That said, I'm a little confused. It looks like you're trying to use `renv` with a project, but you want to change the library paths so that the `renv` library path isn't actually used? You can probably use `renv::deactivate()` to disable `renv` in that project, then re-launch R.

Comment: yes, renv::deactivate() helped me fix this issue

Comment: Can I check with you on whether Renv is the only solution (for R users) to handle package dependencies? I am new to R and trying to learn what other solutions are available to handle package dependencies etc. Basically, is there any other solution(r-package) like R-env?